# Managing has_one relation inline in SilverStripe

Tags: silverstripe

I am wondering if it is possible to directly edit values of a has_one relationship in SilverStripe.

**For example:**

`Person` (extension of `SiteTree`) has one `Job` (extension of `DataObject`) where `Job` has the db fields of title, salary, location etc.

Is it possible in the CMS to place a form in a new tab to edit the values of `Job` form the `Person` page? So all of the form fields from the `Job` DataObject are placed on the `Person` page and will save to the `Job` table when I hit save on the `Person` page?

I can get this to work with inline gridfield editing (thanks to the [editable columns class in gridfieldextensions](https://github.com/silverstripe-australia/silverstripe-gridfieldextensions/blob/master/code/GridFieldEditableColumns.php)) but I believe this requires a has_many / many_many relationship? It also is not suitable for adding images and managing objects that have a large number of fields.

I hope that make sense. Let me know if you need more clarification.

**EDIT:** I found [this hasonefield module](https://github.com/burnbright/silverstripe-hasonefield) which is very out of date but does 80% of what I am after, it would be amazing if it didn't take you off the page though and you could edit the fields within the parent page (`Person`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there is a [fork of simon's orginal has-one-edit module](https://github.com/stevie-mayhew/hasoneedit) that is still available and composer installable, which does the logic for editing fields (or all fields) of a has_one relation. Install it running

```
composer require stevie-mayhew/hasoneedit:1.0.x@stable
```

Then you can define several fields of your has one relation, naming should be `HasOneName-_1_-FieldName`.

From the docs:

> For example, say you have a has_one called `Show` and that has_one has a field called `Title` you want to edit. You'd add the field `TextField::create('Show-_1_-Title', 'Show Title')`.
>
> To add support to your own forms, you need to add the sgn_hasoneedit_UpdateFormExtension extension to your controller and call $this->extend('updateEditForm', $form) before returning the form to the template. Without this, the fields will not get populated with the values from the has_one though saving will work.

Comment: That looks like what I am after! Thanks a lot!